# How to mock the WebResource Rest call

Tags: java, web-services, rest, easymock

How to mock the following  lines of code

```
WebResource jobBuilder = restClient.resource(jobBuilderUrl);
String jobXml = jobBuilder
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(request)
    .post(String.class);
```

I have tried to mock it using easy mock with the following code but it is returning a NullPointerException

```
WebResource jobBuilder = EasyMock.createMock(WebResource.class);
expect(jobBuilder
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(EasyMock.notNull())
    .post(String.class)).andReturn("<test></test>");
replay(jobBuilder);
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to mock the following lines of code

Don't. There's no value in it. Instead start an embedded HTTP server and verify it receives the requests you expect it to. That's what you really care about when writing this code, so that's what you should test. This is very easy to do with the [Simple Framework](http://www.simpleframework.org/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php) or [Jetty](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).

Case in point:

```
jobBuilder
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .entity(request)
    .post(String.class);
```

is identical to:

```
jobBuilder
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .entity(request)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(String.class);
```

is identical to:

```
jobBuilder
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .post(String.class, entity);
```

... and so on. All create the same HTTP request, but all would require different and tightly-coupled test code. That's not how you want your tests to be.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the NullPointerException as well. I got around it by returning a Mock Builder object from the call to accept()

```
ClientResponse clientResponse = createMock(ClientResponse.class);
expect(clientResponse.getStatus()).andReturn(200).anyTimes();
expect(clientResponse.getEntity(FOO.class)).andReturn(jobInfo).anyTimes();
replay(clientResponse);

Builder builder = createMock(Builder.class);
expect(builder.get(ClientResponse.class)).andReturn(clientResponse).anyTimes();
replay(builder);

WebResource jobResource = createMock(WebResource.class);
expect(jobResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn(builder).anyTimes();
replay(jobResource);
```

now the call in my production code

```
ClientResponse response = this.jobResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);

FOO foo = response.getEntity(FOO.class);
```

does what I expect it to.